# railsでmigrationを行っても外部キーが追加されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

railsでmigrationを行ってもschema.rbに外部キーが作られた形跡が見られません。

＊前提
現在railsでTwitterライクなアプリケーションを作っておりまして、ユーザーは複数の投稿をするという機能を実装しています。

＊分からない箇所
migrationファイルで外部キーの設定をしてもschema.rbに反映されていないことに詰まっています。
本来ならschema.rbの一番下に外部キー一覧が表示されると思うのですが、私のファイルはされていません。

＊対象のファイル
db/migration/create_users.rb

```rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :age

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db/migration/create_posts.rb

```rb
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.text :content, null: false
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.string :image, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :posts, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

db/schema.rb

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_08_17_020505) do

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content", null: false
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.string "image"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "email", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest", null: false
    t.string "intro", null: false
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.string "image"
  end

end
```

＊試したこと
追加で以下のようなmigrationファイルを作成してmigrateしましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。

```rb
class AddUserRefToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
   add_foreign_key :posts, :users
  end
end
```

＊環境
rails 5.2

以上、もし分かる方いらっしゃいましたら、ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

実際にはちゃんと外部キーが貼られていると思います。

データベースはsqliteで試してみたのですが、以下の手順で確認できました。

```sh
$ sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3
sqlite> .schema
...
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "posts" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "content" text NOT NULL, "user_id" integer, "image" varchar NOT NULL, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_5b5ddfd518"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("id")
);
...
```

## 追記

github見てると同様のissueがありました。
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35207

コメントを読んでる限りでは、rails6で解消されるようですね。

Comment: @itmammothさん　返信遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。私も確認したところ確かに外部キー制約が貼られておりました。何故、schemaに記載されないかは謎ですが、このまま進めていこうと思います。

Comment: 追記しました。解決したら、チェックを入れておいてくださいね。